# Does the measure of an increasing sequence ALWAYS equal to the limit of the measure of its subsequences?

Tags: probability, limits, measure-theory

I am just starting out on measure theory and will be grateful if someone could clarify this doubt of mine -

One of the properties of a measure λ(.) is given as if {A<sub>n</sub>⊂A<sub>n+1</sub> for all n, then λ(lim<sub>n→∞</sub>A<sub>n</sub>) = λ(∪<sup>∞</sup><sub>n=1</sub>A<sub>n</sub>) = lim<sub>n→∞</sub>(A<sub>n</sub>).

Now, I understand that this property ensures that different measures within the measure space will lead to consistent limits. However, my question is - is this ALWAYS true, irrespective of whether A<sub>n</sub>⊂B (class of measurable sets). My understanding is that this property is only true when A<sub>n</sub> is a subset within a measurable space but not necessarily otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

$\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ is measurable, so all $A_n$ are subsets of a measurable space, therefore there is no otherwise.